# How can I get a list of all CakePHP routes?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all the routes contained in app/Config/routes.php and show them on an admin page.
I'm able to retrieve a [list of controllers](http://www.keyboardninja.eu/programming/list-all-controllers-in-cakephp-2) using `$controllers = App::objects('controller');` and I was wondering if it's possible to do the same for routes.

I've tried using substrings as per the code below but problems that come to mind are commented out routes, white spaces and variations in routes, e.g. links to external resources.  I'm now considering using php's tokenizer but I'd like to know if there is a simple and elegant solution built into CakePHP.

```
$source = file_get_contents(APP . 'Config/routes.php');

$startPos = stripos($source, 'Router::connect(');

$routes = array();

while ($startPos !== false) {

    $endPos = stripos($source, ';', $startPos + 15);

    if($endPos !== false) {

        $route = substr($source, $startPos, $endPos - $startPos);

        $urlStart = stripos($route, "'");
        if($urlStart !== false) {
            $urlEnd = stripos($route, "'", $urlStart + 1);
            $url = substr($route, $urlStart + 1, $urlEnd - $urlStart - 1);
            $routes[] = array('route'=>$route, 'url'=>$url);

        }

        $startPos = stripos($source, 'Router::connect(', $endPos + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: [**`Router::$routes`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Router.html#$routes)

Comment: Thanks very much @ndm, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'd like to mark your comment as an answer if possible.

Comment: Comments cannot be accepted as answers, only actual answers can. Note that you can also answer the question yourself and accept it later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @ndm for the answer, for anyone trying to retrieve a list of routes parsed by CakePHP's Router (i.e. inside app/Config/routes.php) and also those used for any plugins, use `Router::$routes`.  The output can be a [CakeRoute](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-CakeRoute.html) object, RedirectRoute object or a [PluginShortRoute](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-PluginShortRoute.html) object depending on your application.

```
$routes = Router::$routes;
echo('<pre>'); // Readable output
var_dump($routes);
echo('</pre>');
```

For example, the route for `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));` shows:

```
object(CakeRoute)#16 (7)
{
  ["keys"] => array(0) {}
  ["options"] => array(0) {}
  ["defaults"] => array(4)
  {
    ["controller"] => string(5) "pages"
    ["action"] => string(7) "display"
    [0] => string(4) "home"
    ["plugin"] => NULL
  }
  ["template"] => string(1) "/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `bin/cake routes` [Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/fr/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html)

And also use for JSON export :

```
public function routes() {
    $routes = Router::routes();
    return $this->response->withStringBodyAsJson($routes);
}
```

If you want to list All Routes, including Controllers auto-generated routes see here [list-all-controllers-actions-in-cakephp-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892594/list-all-controllers-actions-in-cakephp-3) , Note : you have to edit this script if you use prefix.