# CakePHP: where to keep a list of all admin actions?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can do the `admin_edit`, `admin_delete`, `admin_print` and `admin_manage_tags` actions on an `ArticlesController`, those actions will require an `$id` passed. I can also do `admin_create` or `admin_sort` without an `$id`. Finally, `admin_delete` will require `POST`, all others should use `GET`.

How and where do I store all those rules in CakePHP in a way so I can easily access or update them all and have the corresponding action links renderd on the items list page, the edit page, or anywhere else automatically?

For example, I have a list page of all articles (`admin_index`), and would like to render the direct links to the editing or printing pages. I know I can hardcode them, but if I add some new functionality, such as `admin_render_pdf`, I'd have to go through all views and put it there manually. Same if I rename or remove an action.

Furthermore, having a common source of all admin actions could even allow me to render the admin navigation automatically.

Do I define an array somewhere manually, or does CakePHP have some magic that'd retrieve those for me? What is the commonly used / best practice in this case?

The closest I could find was this [list-all-controllers-actions-in-cakephp-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892594/list-all-controllers-actions-in-cakephp-3) but it looks like it's mostly ACL-related.

Comment: I've no such experience with cakephp, but as I remember from an old tutorial, cake php allows namespaces/modules. create an admin  namespace or module, whatever it is, and move all existing controlelrs there.or recreate admin controllers or generate whole CRUD controllers with bake. 

If you don't want to  change your structure, just add `YourExistingApp::path('YourController', [other params])`

Comment: Are you working with CakePHP 2 (as tagged) or CakePHP 3 (as in the link you posted at the end)? In case of CakePHP 2: Did you have a look at "elements"? This would be a solution at least for a admin main navigation. But all links with different IDs involved (edit/delete etc.) should be manual coded in the corresponding templates, I think there is no automatic way...